# I am trying to perform search operation in swift

Tags: swift, search, filter, nsarray

1. I have an array of managed object class named as **categories**
2. In every category, I have NSSet of **apCodes**
3. I am showing the category name in the table view section and opCodes name in table view rows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeFMq.png)

- I want to search operation by apcodes, not by category name, but I want to show only those categories whose apcode name matches with the search text.

Here is my code, please correct my function, I unable to filter apcodes properly.

Note: I have copied the original **categories** array in **originalCategories**

```
 func filterArray(text : String) {
    categories = originalCategories
    categories = categories?.compactMap { category in
        guard !text.isEmpty else {
            return category
        }

        var apCodes = [ApCode]()
        if let apc = category.apCodes?.allObjects as? [ApCode] {
            apCodes = apc.filter { (apcode) -> Bool in
                if apcode.apCodeName?.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) ?? false {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        if apCodes.count == 0 {
            return nil
        } else {
            category.apCodes = NSSet(array: apCodes)
            return category
        }
    }
    
    if text == Constant.EMPTY_STRING {
        categories = originalCategories
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns to the higher-order CompactMap function. where I am mapping categories.

Comment: Your filter should look like this `originalCategories.filter { $0.apCodes.contains(where: { $0.name == text })}` (I haven't bothered with possible optional values)